# List just the AMI ID.

Tags: batch-file, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, amazon-ami

I want to print just the AMI id's inside a text file without the rest of the image's attributes.

I have been struggling to print out just the AMI ID from the AWS CLI.  What I have is below:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --query "Images[].[ImageID]" --output text > C:\output.txt
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`aws ec2 describe-images --output text --query 'Images[*].{ID:ImageId}'`

Note that this command returns *all* images available to you (public and private) so it will be a long list. Use the `--owners` flag to only show images belonging to specific owners.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too clear *which* AMI ID you wish to retrieve.

If you wish to run a command **on an Amazon EC2 instance** to display the AMI being used by **that** EC2 instance, then use:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id
```

It will display the AMI ID that was used to launch the EC2 instance on which the command is run.